# WP - cURL call to an externa API stopped working- cURL Error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

Tags: wordpress, ssl, curl, ovh

I have created some 'basic' API calls using cURL on a WP website that have been working until last Friday.

Since then I receive this error message.
Error n: 60,
Error: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired.

Now I just checked on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ombri-immo.lu
(ombri-immo.lu is the domain of the website) and the certificate is still valid.

(To be thorough I have two website that call the same API and give back the same error)

```
 $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://middleware-production.easy2pilot-v8.com/api/***/token',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "login": "**",
    "password": "**"
  }',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    ),
  ));
  
  $response = curl_exec($ch);

  echo 'GETINFO: ' . curl_getinfo($ch) . '<br/>';
  echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
  echo 'CURL ERROR: ' . curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';

  curl_close($ch);
  echo $response;
```

This is the code of the call. The credentials work properly since I tested them on Postman and everything is fine.

I have read many posts and most of them suggest touching thing on the server side, which I have no access to and no knowledge about functioning, I take for granted that it is the domain provider (OVH) that id taking care of that.

Also I am not completely in charge of the project and know for a fact that WordPress is not up to date (Hopefully this will happen tomorrow and will fix everything :) ) and also I have noticed that the curl version installed on the server is old ( again I have contacted the reseller and asked him to update that.

Does anybody have any suggestions on things to try or if for example the domain and server provider should be able to take care of this?

Thanks for taking the time of reading the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I can see is with your CA bundle that is not correct in ombri-immo.lu domain so it must be updated.

Certificate Chain: The certificate chain does **NOT** validate.

This certificate was issued by the R3 CA bundle.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEZTCCA02gAwIBAgIQQAF1BIMUpMghjISpDBbN3zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA/
MSQwIgYDVQQKExtEaWdpdGFsIFNpZ25hdHVyZSBUcnVzdCBDby4xFzAVBgNVBAMT
DkRTVCBSb290IENBIFgzMB4XDTIwMTAwNzE5MjE0MFoXDTIxMDkyOTE5MjE0MFow
MjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFjAUBgNVBAoTDUxldCdzIEVuY3J5cHQxCzAJBgNVBAMT
AlIzMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuwIVKMz2oJTTDxLs
jVWSw/iC8ZmmekKIp10mqrUrucVMsa+Oa/l1yKPXD0eUFFU1V4yeqKI5GfWCPEKp
Tm71O8Mu243AsFzzWTjn7c9p8FoLG77AlCQlh/o3cbMT5xys4Zvv2+Q7RVJFlqnB
U840yFLuta7tj95gcOKlVKu2bQ6XpUA0ayvTvGbrZjR8+muLj1cpmfgwF126cm/7
gcWt0oZYPRfH5wm78Sv3htzB2nFd1EbjzK0lwYi8YGd1ZrPxGPeiXOZT/zqItkel
/xMY6pgJdz+dU/nPAeX1pnAXFK9jpP+Zs5Od3FOnBv5IhR2haa4ldbsTzFID9e1R
oYvbFQIDAQABo4IBaDCCAWQwEgYDVR0TAQH/BAgwBgEB/wIBADAOBgNVHQ8BAf8E
BAMCAYYwSwYIKwYBBQUHAQEEPzA9MDsGCCsGAQUFBzAChi9odHRwOi8vYXBwcy5p
ZGVudHJ1c3QuY29tL3Jvb3RzL2RzdHJvb3RjYXgzLnA3YzAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBTE
p7Gkeyxx+tvhS5B1/8QVYIWJEDBUBgNVHSAETTBLMAgGBmeBDAECATA/BgsrBgEE
AYLfEwEBATAwMC4GCCsGAQUFBwIBFiJodHRwOi8vY3BzLnJvb3QteDEubGV0c2Vu
Y3J5cHQub3JnMDwGA1UdHwQ1MDMwMaAvoC2GK2h0dHA6Ly9jcmwuaWRlbnRydXN0
LmNvbS9EU1RST09UQ0FYM0NSTC5jcmwwHQYDVR0OBBYEFBQusxe3WFbLrlAJQOYf
r52LFMLGMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjANBgkqhkiG9w0B
AQsFAAOCAQEA2UzgyfWEiDcx27sT4rP8i2tiEmxYt0l+PAK3qB8oYevO4C5z70kH
ejWEHx2taPDY/laBL21/WKZuNTYQHHPD5b1tXgHXbnL7KqC401dk5VvCadTQsvd8
S8MXjohyc9z9/G2948kLjmE6Flh9dDYrVYA9x2O+hEPGOaEOa1eePynBgPayvUfL
qjBstzLhWVQLGAkXXmNs+5ZnPBxzDJOLxhF2JIbeQAcH5H0tZrUlo5ZYyOqA7s9p
O5b85o3AM/OJ+CktFBQtfvBhcJVd9wvlwPsk+uyOy2HI7mNxKKgsBTt375teA2Tw
UdHkhVNcsAKX1H7GNNLOEADksd86wuoXvg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

You can confirm in [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ombri-immo.lu) -> Certification Paths -> Select any `Mozilla|Apple|Android|Java|Windows` -> Path #2: Not trusted (invalid certificate [Fingerprint SHA256: 0687260331a72403d909f105e69bcf0d32e1bd2493ffc6d9206d11bcd6770739]) -> 4 In trust store

```
DST Root CA X3   Self-signed
Fingerprint SHA256: 0687260331a72403d909f105e69bcf0d32e1bd2493ffc6d9206d11bcd6770739
Pin SHA256: Vjs8r4z+80wjNcr1YKepWQboSIRi63WsWXhIMN+eWys=
RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA1withRSA
Valid until: Thu, 30 Sep 2021 14:01:15 UTC
EXPIRED
Weak or insecure signature, but no impact on root certificate
```